# Mac OSX: LoadModule wsgi_module not working as mentioned in docs

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, macos-sierra

I upgraded apache from 2.4.25 to 2.4.29 due to security reasons in Mac OSX. 
Also installed mod_wsgi via pip.

Now facing difficulty while restarting the apache server!

I ran this command as per the mod_wsgi [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi),

```
> mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7"
```

Copied the above two lines in `apache.conf` file and tried to start the apache server but getting the following error:

```
> sudo apachectl start
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl: line 79: 51863 Illegal instruction: 4  $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** as per Graham answer:

```
# I upgraded the mod_wsgi
> sudo pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Downloading mod_wsgi-4.5.21.tar.gz (2.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.5MB 2.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Found existing installation: mod-wsgi 4.5.20
    Uninstalling mod-wsgi-4.5.20:
      Successfully uninstalled mod-wsgi-4.5.20
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... done
Successfully installed mod-wsgi-4.5.21
```

But when i tried:

```
> mod_wsgi-express start-server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/bin/mod_wsgi-express", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mod-wsgi==4.5.21', 'console_scripts', 'mod_wsgi-express')()
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 3484, in main
    cmd_start_server(args)
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 3332, in cmd_start_server
    config = _cmd_setup_server('start-server', args, vars(options))
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 2999, in _cmd_setup_server
    language, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/DSFENV/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

getting the above error. 
Also I have installed apache 2.4.29 following this [blog](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/):

**2nd Edit**
I have resolved `ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8`, now the output of `mod_wsgi-express start-server` shows:

```
> mod_wsgi-express start-server
Server URL         : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:501
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:501/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:501/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

But when I try to do config test, still showing the same error:

```
> sudo apachectl configtest
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl: line 79: 53944 Illegal instruction: 4  $HTTPD -t
```

xcode version:

```
> xcodebuild -version
Xcode 8.3.2
Build version 8E2002
```

**3rd EDIT** as per comments:

```
> /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
Illegal instruction: 4

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
-bash: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so: cannot execute binary file

> sys.prefix
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'

> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]'
```

I followed this blog to install Apache 2.4.29:
http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/
**--with-ssl** option as we need to https for the website.

**4th EDIT**:

```
> file /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

> file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [i386: Mach-O bundle i386]
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386
```

Please let me know how to proceed forward.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton Please provide your valuable feedback for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have updated your Apache installation in some way, usually the mod_wsgi.so binary from an older release should still work as Apache maintains ABI compatibility across patch level updates.

If it isn't working, then you may need to re-build mod_wsgi. If there is no newer version of mod_wsgi, you will need to force a full re-build to ensure cached binaries from `pip` cache are not used.

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir mod_wsgi
```

Next problem though is if you have upgraded to Xcode 9.1, Apple have further broken things by completely removing `apxs`, meaning that my prior workaround for Apple brokeness no longer works. In this case you need to ensure you are installing mod_wsgi 4.5.21 or later. That version only just got released with fixes to accomodate for Xcode 9.1

So try that `pip` command above and make sure `mod_wsgi-express` still works by running:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server
```

Then validate configuration snippet to use in Apache config by running again:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

If still issues with main Apache, then ensure you do a complete stop of Apache and then a start, and not just restart. Let me know how that all goes.

---

UPDATE 1

Above presumes you were using Apple supplied Apache in respect of Xcode 9.1 comments. You seem to be using your own Apache, maybe form Homebrew. Still try the same thing.

Comment: I have updated the question based on your answer. Awaiting your valuable feedback.

Comment: I have given a second edit to the question. Please look into the same.

Comment: What do you get for ``sys.prefix`` and ``sys.version`` out of Python? What is ``LANG`` set to in your environment?

Comment: What do you get if you run ``file /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd`` and ``file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so``.

Comment: I have updated the question as requested. Please do look into it. Thanks a lot for your time, much appreciated!

Comment: I did not want you to run those files, I wanted you to run the ``file`` command with them as argument. This will indicate what architectures are built into the binaries. Am trying to confirm they are all 64 bit or whether for some reason they aren't.

Comment: Also, have you installed ``gcc`` from Homebrew?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159206/discussion-between-abijith-mg-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: The best place for further discussion is the mod_wsgi mailing list. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: Ok, Graham. Posted the same question in the google group. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Graham:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir mod_wsgi
```

Upgrade to **mod_wsgi 4.5.22** did the trick.

Comment: Personally I know of no reason why an older version of mod_wsgi wouldn't work with Apache 2.4.27. For MacOS X, the problem with older versions of mod_wsgi is going to be due to changes in Xcode 9.0 and 9.1 if using Apple Apache distro. If use older versions with those versions of Xcode, compilation out of the box will fail. That has nothing to do with the Apache version though. If using non Apple Apache, so long as correct ``apxs`` found, it should work regardless.

Comment: Oh ok. Makes sense now. Will modify the answer.